# SCF Service Message Contract Namespace coming in soap request

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I have a WCF service and I have tags like

```
<DataAttributes>
   <DataAttribute>
      -- Some Data Here --
   </DataAttribute>
   <DataAttribute>
      -- Some Data Here --
   </DataAttribute>
</DataAttributes>
```

And I tested my service in SoapUI, but it is showing contracts with some extension as:

```
<MyServiceNS:DataAttributes>
   <MyServiceNS:DataAttribute>
      -- Some Data Here --
   </DataAttribute>
   <MyServiceNS:DataAttribute>
      -- Some Data Here --
   </DataAttribute>
</DataAttributes>
```

But I want my contracts appear as they are in contracts.
If somebody can give the solution, Thanks in advance.

I am using [MessageContract]

Answer (score 0):

both samples are the same (assuming the first one has a default namespace earlier on). prefix vs. default namespace should not really matter.